# CREATE TABLE with multiple words in a single column

Tags: postgresql

I can create a table with single name of a column, E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable 
(
    Name text,
    Age int
)
```

How can I create a single column with multiple words? E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable 
(
    Person Name text,
    Person Age int
)
```

When I use this, it gives me error. Couldn't find solution anywhere.

Comment: Delimiter is `"` in postgres but why do you want to do that?You`ll have to use delimiters each time you reference that column

Comment: Here is the relevant link to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the column names with `"`:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
"Person Name" text,
"Person Age" int);
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/52d05/1/0)**</kbd>

**[Quoted identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)**

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in **double-quotes (")**.
>
> Quoted identifiers can contain any character, except the character
> with code zero. (To include a double quote, write two double quotes.)
> This allows constructing table or column names that would otherwise
> not be possible, **such as ones containing spaces** or ampersands. The
> length limitation still applies.

Comment: @joojoo: although this is the correct answer and will work, _using_ this kind of column names is not really recommended. This will give you a lot more trouble in the long run that it's actually worth it

Comment: Got it. Thanks @lad2025!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to quote (`"`) these names to force the database to do this. In practice, this is *extremely* annoying and unproductive, as noted in a few comments. If you do this, then *every* time you need to reference this column, you will have to

- quote it with double quote
- match its case exactly

So this:

```
SELECT testTable."person name" FROM testTable
```

will throw an error because I didn't capitalize `p` or `n`.

This will result in much wasted time looking up the exact format of the name every time you reference it.

The much more common and easier solution is to simply use **underscores**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    person_name text,
    person_age int
)
```

I, and I believe much of our industry, would usually regard names containing spaces (or any other character that requires me to quote the name) as a sign of inexperience or lack of knowledge.